# Override web page style in Android WebView

Tags: android

I want to load a webpage on android Webview. Is there a way to override some CSS component of the web page in my android webView?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29570248/change-page-styles-android-webview/29570426#29570426

Answer (score 0):

Upload your customized css somewhere. You can apply your new css using Javascript. You can inject following javascript after the `WebView` is finished loading:

```
var link = document.createElement("link");
link.href = "http://example.com/mystyle.css";
link.type = "text/css";
link.rel = "stylesheet";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(link);
```

So your final Java code will look something like this:

```
String jsToInject = "var link=document.createElement('link');link.href='http://example.com/mystyle.css';link.type ='text/css'; link.rel ='stylesheet';document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);"
myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:" + jsToInject);
```